# How to migrate Ubuntu system to another Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

Ok, here is the thing. I have two exactly same servers and I finished the entire configuration of server number one (Apache, MySQL, postfix...).

I did also a lot about security and now i wanna migrate server configuration to server number two, where I have installed same Ubuntu server 14.04.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the servers are completely identical, disk cloning is the easiest solution.

Just use any disk cloning utility (there are lots of them around); in a pinch, even `dd` will do.

If you have a hardware RAID-1 configuration, you can also take a disk from the first server, put it in the second server, and rebuild the mirror on both machines; you'll end up with two identical servers.

Comment: With disk cloning, your UUID's for your disks will be identical, which could get your intro trouble later.  The RAID1 approach wouldn't have that problem.